# PopOverController resize at Top of View

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uipopovercontroller

Is there a way that I can calculate/detect if PopOverController is at the top of View? If so a way to have it show permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown vs permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp depending if you are at the bottom or top of view or if there is enough room to show the popOverControl without resizing?Alternative I was thinking of scrolling the view down or up if there isn't enough room, but I would like to utilize permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown and permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp. Any suggestions?

Comment: you have to check your Y position of your touch point. calculate the room and show according

Comment: so what what is the coordinate for the absolute top of the View ? do I have to get Y coordinate of the UIWindow? or is it as easy as the top being 0 ?

Comment: you can check through the touch event

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to calculate where the popover controller is going to put the view. The popover controller is designed to let you specify the location of where the arrow ***could*** point to as well as the view in which the popover will be added. Then the popover controller will calculate where it has room to display its popover view.

However, if you can limit where the popover controller places the popover view by specifying one or more `UIPopoverArrowDirection`. For example, let's say you have a large view (view A) with a smaller subview (view B) positioned on the left side of view A. If you want to show a popover for the button view located to the right of view B, when you present it, you can tell the popover controller to only show its popover view to the right of the button's frame within view A like so:

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect: buttonView.frame
                                   inView: viewA
                 permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
                                 animated: YES];
```

[image]

**Edit**

Can you get the frame of the text field in the coordinate space of the view containing the table view?

```
CGRect frame = [tableView.superview convertRect: textField.frame fromView: textField.superview];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect: frame
                                   inView: tableView.superview
                 permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
                                 animated: YES];
```

Assuming the tableView's super view is large enough for your needs, this should accommodate the display of the popover.

Comment: In the current project Im working on I have the PopOver showing on top of a UITextField inside a UITableviewCell. If Im at the top of the UItableviewCell the UIPopOverControl resizes to a smaller size preventing the items from being visible. I have to have the inview located on top or under UITextField

Answer (score 0):

get the your touch coordinate from

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:myView];
    NSLog("%lf %lf", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
}
```

After you get X and Y point you can calculate available space for opening your PopOverController.

Please let me know if you need further help